# cannot find module 'cookie' while using the express module

Tags: express, session-cookies

I need your help on building rest API using express..  I have tried many versions of express. that also have CookieParser middleware but I'm just getting the above error...

```
  Error: Cannot find module 'cookie'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)`
```

I installed the cookie-parser globally and using Express version 4.... the code snippet is below.

```
var express = require('express'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
session = require('express-session'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
api = require('./routes/api.js') ,  
app = express();
```

app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'angcms', 
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());

Comment: Are you correctly require that module (require('cookie-parser'))?

Comment: I thought require('cookie-parser') can also work... Well when I try to remove the cookie folder from the express node_modules and put in the global location ,  the problem disappears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like npm has screwed up your module installation is all. Try reinstalling this module completely.

Uninstalling complete module

```
$ npm uninstall cookie-parser
```

after uninstalling the module, install it again using below command

```
$ npm install cookie-parser -g
```

**Note:** if you have not installed before then install first and the execute .

Answer (score 10):

I had the same situation. I solved by this way:

```
$ npm install
```

You must type this inside the Project folder. If i understood, "npm install" check the project dependencies registered on JSON files.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't install the typescript define of cookie-parser module, install `@types/cookie-parser` to solve it.

```
$ npm install @types/cookie-parser -D
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, create another project and install cookie  or open other project that have cookie installed and open `node_module` and copy the folder cookie and replace it.

This problem happens because you have `npm` and `yarn` installed
if you open the node module folder, the cookie folder is empty
because yarn or `npm` did not install the package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Azure, no one of the solutions above worked.
This one solved my problem:

```
npm i yarn -g
yarn add cookie-parser
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the issue and I am not sure what the reason was but what fixed it for me was to go in `node_modules/cookie-parser` and look at the `package.json` inside it.
I then installed the dependancies listed there and it solved the problem.

(Those dependancies were `cookie` and `cookie-signature`)